# Editing a Template in word to remove ugly spaces

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office

i'm working on a book and i have to go with template of word but there is a problem with that template,  look at the image and you will understand

[image]

the problem is when i use `shift+enter` They give me those ugly spaces.i fix it using this options

1. select the text
2. go to paragraph and add don't addd spaces between paragraph
3. then if i use `shift+enter` it will be like the image below

[image]

but i'm not satisfied because i have to do it many time.

Comment: You really should not be using line breaks (shift-enter) when you need a paragraph break (enter). it is also a good idea to edit your Word document with paragraph marks and other invisible characters unhidden. Which reveals exactly what the cause of this kind of problem is at a glance

Comment: It's also a good idea to add space after points and commas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right click on the style (top of the page in the **Home** tab) in the template and click on Modify. Select Format at the bottom left and choose Paragraph. Here you can set the spacing how you like for the whole document.

Answer (score 0):

In case the formatting is really stubborn, cut and paste the entire document into Notepad, then cut and paste again from notepad back into a new, clean word document. This method completely removes all the formatting.